# If I install Ubuntu along side Windows 8 can I designate either OS more space later?

Tags: dual-boot

So if I give Windows 8 more space to begin with, will I be able to give Ubuntu more space later if I change my mind?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but this would be easily done using the Ubuntu Live USB because it would not be using the Ubuntu or Windows OS partition while loaded.

From within the Ubuntu Live USB you can open Dash and run GParted. From there simply resize whichever you want to have more/less space and done. After reboot each one will refresh the amount of space for their respective partitions.

For the cases I had worked on which are similar to your question, they normally tend to be because they can't share information between both systems. In case this is also your case (You would have to confirm just in  case it is), then my suggestion is to run the Ubuntu Live USB as mentioned above, but this time, create a 3rd partition in either FAT32 or NTFS. This way, this partition can be the bridge between sharing both systems the same information.

Note that, since you are talking about Windows 8, I will assumed it was pre-installed, so for this case, the recommended version of Ubuntu should be 15.04 to avoid other problems mentioned in the [Windows 8 Pre-installed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-8-64-bit-system-uefi-supported/228069#228069) answer.